# T SQL: Find row in 2nd Table - with most recent Date - Before Date in current Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

I work for a Group of Federal & State funded Health Clinics [Community Health Centers].

Every time a Patient has a Visit, the Patient's current Health Insurance on the date of the Visit is recorded.

When Patients have Babies, they are born at a Hospital that does not send us the Patient's Health Insurance on the date of the Delivery.

I have a dataset [Deliveries] with a list of Patients and the Date[s] they had babies born over the last three years.

I have a separate dataset [Visits] with all Visits [at one of our Clinics] for all patients from the 'Deliveries' dataset. This dataset contains the Health Insurance for each Patient at each Visit.

Expected output:

```
Patient, Delivery Date, Most Recent Visit, Health Insurance
```

For each Patient I need to add the Insurance at the last [most recent] Visit at one of our Clinics *before* the baby was born.

I hope I've explained sufficiently.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Example:

**Deliveries**:

```
Patient        Delivery Date
----------------------------
A              2017-02-22
A              2018-04-16
A              2019-07-12
```

**Visits**:

```
Patient        Visit Date        Insurance
------------------------------------------        
A              2017-01-10        X
A              2017-01-23        Y
A              2018-01-12        W 
A              2018-03-22        P
A              2019-04-16        R
A              2019-06-12        S
```

Expected output:

```
Patient        Delivery Date      Most Recent Visit        Insurance
-----------------------------------------------------------------------    
A              2017-02-22         2017-01-23                Y
A              2018-04-16         2018-03-22                P
A              2019-07-12         2019-06-12                S
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a lateral join:

```
selet d.*, v.visit_date most_recent_visit, v.insurance
from deliveries d
outer apply (
    select top (1) v.*
    from visits v
    where v.patient = d.patient and v.visit_date < d.delivery_date
    order by v.visit_date desc
) d
```